# Facebook Developer - Cannot Create Developer Account

Tags: account

When I try visiting the following page and clicking the "Create Developer Account" button in Step 2, a modal loads and then disappears immediately.

Page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Console Errors: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (dialog, line 0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Facebook customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: That is fine. Sorry if it was off-topic, but I appreciate NightWing's response. It got me where I needed to go, so thank you NightWing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

after you log in. It should say "Get Started" click on it and it will allow you to create a developer account that way.